# Deactivate two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

My macros are stored in the personal workbook. I have 3 workbooks open. One workbook is generated always from a web application. Therefore the name is always changing (I have no influence on the web app). However, the two other workbook are named properly.
I would like to deactivate at the end of the subrutine the two named macros in order to get back at the original exported excel file.

Version 1:
I activate the exported excel file. In this case I have to modify the macro at each time when I work with this file.

```
Windows("exported_excel_file.xlsx").Activate
```

Version 2:
I deactive the two other excel files. But I do not find a deactivate method:

```
Windows("exported_excel_file.xlsx").Deactivate
```

What kind of solutions are avaiable?

Comment: `Set` your books instead?

Comment: Only 1 workbook is active at any one time, so by activating a workbook you are inherently *deactivating* the other workbooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the workbooks instead:

```
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    Select Case wb.Name
        Case "exported_excel_file.xlsx"
        Case "some_other_file.xlsx"
        Case Else: wb.Activate: Exit For
    End Select
Next
```